# How to inline functions in Common Lisp

Tags: common-lisp, inline

Could someone show me how to inline a function in Common Lisp?
I have a lot of small functions which are called all the time so it would be good to save the cost of these function calls.

For example, how would you inline the "standalone" function inside the "caller" function?

```
(defun standalone ()
 (* 2 5))

(defun caller ()
 (standalone))
```

Comment: What you need is a variable for that, not a function!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
(declaim (inline standalone))

(defun standalone ()
 (* 2 5))

(defun caller ()
 (standalone))
```

Documentation is [here](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/d_inline.htm).

(But keep in mind that defining a function that *always* returns the numeric literal 10 doesn't make much sense...)

Comment: Thank you a lot, it works. Indeed the "standalone" function doesn't make any sense but I wondered about the cost of a function call, and I found that "standalone" takes 0.42 seconds when "caller" takes 0.61 seconds (to execute 100000000 times). So it appears that the added function call consumes 50% of the total "standalone" function cost. I don't know how this cost compares to other languages but still, I found it expensive enough to worry about.

Comment: As Ehvince points out in his answer, inlining or not is a trade-off between code size and execution time. The call mechanism for all languages is similar: push on the stack the return address, the value of all registers that will be altered, as well as the parameter values, make the call, pop the parameters off the stack; then, at the end of the subroutine call, restore the registers and return address, restore stack and resume execution from there. There are many possible complications (such as how return values are handled), but, yes, function calls are expensive. Unreadable code more so...

Answer (score 4):

See the Cookbook: https://lispcookbook.github.io/cl-cookbook/performance.html#code-inline

The declaration inline replaces function calls with function body, if the compiler supports it. It will save the cost of function calls but will potentially increase the code size. The best situation to use inline might be those small but frequently used functions. The following snippets show how to encourage and prohibit code inline.

```
;; The globally defined function DISPATCH should be open-coded,
;; if the implementation supports inlining, unless a NOTINLINE 
;; declaration overrides this effect.
(declaim (inline dispatch))
(defun dispatch (x) (funcall (get (car x) 'dispatch) x))

;; Here is an example where inlining would be encouraged.
;; Because function DISPATCH was defined as INLINE, the code 
;; inlining will be encouraged by default.
(defun use-dispatch-inline-by-default () 
  (dispatch (read-command)))

;; Here is an example where inlining would be prohibited.
;; The NOTINLINE here only affects this function.
(defun use-dispatch-with-declare-notinline  ()
  (declare (notinline dispatch))
  (dispatch (read-command)))

;; Here is an example where inlining would be prohibited.
;; The NOTINLINE here affects all following code.
(declaim (notinline dispatch))
(defun use-dispatch-with-declaim-noinline () 
  (dispatch (read-command)))

;; Inlining would be encouraged becuase you specified it.
;; The INLINE here only affects this function.
(defun use-dispatch-with-inline () 
  (declare (inline dispatch))
  (dispatch (read-command)))
```

Comment: Thank you for this great ressource :)

Answer (score 2):

Some implementations like the Allegro CL compiler [ignore *inline* declarations](https://franz.com/support/documentation/current/doc/compiling.htm#inline-ignored-2).

[Compiler macros](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/03_bba.htm) as created by `define-compiler-macro` (different from `defmacro`!) can be also used instead to inline code.

Comment: Interesting. Unfamiliar with Allegro CL. "User defined functions are never compiled inline." Find that strange for a commercial product. Unconvinced by their reasons.